# How to Install the Mathematica Iso File?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, iso, mathematica

From my university, I got access to Mathematica 12.2.0. I downloaded the file, which is an `.iso`-file. Just checked with the university that this is correct, but they couldn't help me on how to *install* this iso-file. The [Mathematica Installation Guide for Linux](https://support.wolfram.com/12453) does not have any hints about it, as they only show it when your downloaded file is an `.sh`-one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't install an ISO. You either burn it to a CD/DVD/USB or you mount it. Consider it the same as a live Ubuntu session you download and burn.

Depending on the content you can then install software or execute a script to start software from the device/mount.